# Можно ли задавать числа колесиком мыши в PhpStorm?

Tags: css, phpstorm

Возможно ли в PhpStorm изменять параметры заданные в CSS с помощью колесика мыши? Например, я задал высоту в пикселях и чтобы не стирать - писать числа каждый раз прибавляя/отнимая единичку, а просто крутить колесико мышки, как в инструментах разработчика хрома или Sublime Text.

Comment: Мне кажется это был бы хороший feature request. Попробуйте создать заявку на https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/

Comment: Да надо будет написать, надеюсь откликнутся